# My circular divs get stuck midway flipping when hovering and two of my divs can't get above the bottom div on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a responsive and functional diagram that when I hover it flips and shows information.
So I made this Venn diagram with three circular divs on top of each other and when I hover my mouse over one of the divs it enlarges and flips showing information on the other side. What I get is a buggy transformation when hovering. I am not sure how to make the flipping smoother when hovering because right now I need to get my cursor on a specific area so the circle fully flips around and not get stuck. I tried using margin and padding for the ":hover" but that doesn't really work and it would also look too spaced out. Secondly is that when hovering on the top two circular divs they enlarge (like they are supposed to) and go above each other but never above the bottom circular div. I tried using z-index with a huge number but still doesn't make it go above the divs. Also, on javascript how would I make it so that when hovering the other circles have a blur?

It should look something like what I prototyped on figma.
[The venn diagram](https://www.figma.com/proto/6VQQrBhef7uR3QRseeVKcK/Untitled?node-id=1%3A37&scaling=min-zoom&page-id=0%3A1)

And here is the HTML, CSS, and Javascript I used to make this version of the venn diagram.(Don't mind how I formatted the information in the paragraph.)

```js
const circles = document.querySelectorAll('.circle');

circles.forEach((circle) => {
  circle.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    removeActiveClasses();
    circle.classList.add('circleactive');
  });
});

function removeActiveClasses() {
  circles.forEach((circle) => {
    circle.classList.remove('circleactive');

  });
}
```

```css
#ven_diagram {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 355px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#top {
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateX(0%) translateY(10%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

#bottom {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 24%;
  /*transform: translateX(0%) translateY(-40%);*/
}

.circle {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 3px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circleactive {
  width: 260px;
  height: 260px;
  z-index: 900;
  transition: 1s ease-in;
}

.circletitle {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  text-shadow: 5px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

#circle1 {
  background: rgba(33, 218, 223, 1);
  transform: translateX(25%) translateY(0%);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in;
}

#circle1:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.circle .side {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.side .circle3p {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#circle2 {
  background: rgba(95, 216, 21, .78);
  transform: translateX(-25%) translateY(0%);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in;
}
#circle2:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
#circle3 {
  background: rgba(253, 45, 45, .8);
  transform: translateX(0%) translateY(-10%);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in;
}
#circle3:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
#circle1 span {
  margin-right: 50%;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(184, 184, 184, 0.70);
  backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
}

#circle2 span {
  margin-left: 50%;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(184, 184, 184, 0.70);
  backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
}

#circle3 span {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(184, 184, 184, 0.70);
  backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
}

#circle1p {
  display: none;
}

#circle2p {
  display: none;
}

#circle3p {
  display: none;
}

#section1 {
  height: 100vh;
}

#section1 h1 {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<section id="section1" class="section">
  <div id="ven_diagram">
    <div id="top" class="absol">
      <div id="circle1" class="circle side" onmouseleave="removeActiveClasses();"><span>Mind</span>
        <p class="side circle3p">has to do with how a person thinks, feels and acts as he or she copes with life. A person with good emotional health can feel, express and respond to a wide range of emotions in healthy ways and form healthy relationships with others</p>
      </div>
      <div id="circle2" class="circle side" onmouseleave="removeActiveClasses();"><span>Social</span>
        <p class="side circle3p">has to do with your relationships with others. People with good social health can connect with and contribute to family, friends, and the wider community</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom" class="absol">
      <span class="circletitle">Mental Health</span>
      <div id="circle3" class="circle side" onmouseleave="removeActiveClasses();"><span>Spiritual</span>
        <p class="side circle3p">has to do with how you find meaning and purpose in your life. People with good spiritual health have a sense of something bigger than themselves and their own day-to-day lives</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Mental wellness according to the World Health Organization, is defined as “a state of well-being in which the individual realizes his or her own abilities, can cope with the normal stresses of life, can work productively and fruitfully, and is able
      to make a contribution to his or her community.”</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Only circle1 has a rotate on hover so the others never rotate. Also you seem to be overwriting transforms. Only the last one applied will be used - is this part of the problem? Tidying up the CSS so that for example everything that is common to all circles is defined just the once under a .circle might help see more clearly what is going on.

Comment: I just updated the code and all the circles should flip. I am running the code here and the hover is running smoothly I am not sure what changed but before even circle1 had trouble fully flipping over.

Comment: You can now end up with two circles flipping at once which I guess you don't want?

Comment: Yes, and I would also like to make it that any of the circles I am hovering on be above all the other circles including "mental health" so the information is more visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are problems with the flipping of circles, things moving incorrectly and a requirement that a hovered circle appears above the others.

A further problem, though scarcely visible, is that making an element have an opacity less than 1 means that everything within it also has opacity less than 1 - so in this case the titles of two of the circles were fainter. We get round this by putting the background color on a before pseudo element so we can set its opacity independently.

Also, the blur made text blur, and the code did not make the text fill the circles.

This snippet attempts to get round these problems - the main change is that positioning is done absolute and without the separate top and bottom divs. The three circle elements are drawn within the ven_diagram element which is 'shrunk' so that they overlap.

CSS variables are used to define some dimensions so they should be easy to change and almost everything is done in terms of vmin to make the diagram responsive (including font-size) though you could substitute px if responsiveness at this level is not required.

An alteration had to be made to the sensing of mouse movements as there are overlapping elements, so one element's mouseover could be another element's mouseout. mouseleave/enter are used instead and the active circle only made inactive if the mouse leaves it, not a neighbouring circle.

The blurring of other circles when one is hovered over has not been implemented. Instead the background color has been made opacity 1 to put the text on a clearer background.

More 'tidying up' is probably possible, but hopefully this will help start on the process:

```js
const diagram = document.querySelector('#ven_diagram');
const circles = document.querySelectorAll('.circle');

circles.forEach((circle) => {
  circle.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    removeActiveClasses();
    circle.classList.add('circleactive');
    diagram.classList.add('isactive');   
  });
});

function removeActiveClasses() {
  circles.forEach((circle) => {
    circle.classList.remove('circleactive');
  });
  diagram.classList.remove('isactive');
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#ven_diagram {
  --unit: 1vmin;
  --cw: 40;/* diameter of each circle in var(--unit) units */
  --overlap: 0.333; /* the venn diagram will be reduced by this much of cw (so as to get overlap) */
  position: relative;
  width: calc(((2 * var(--cw)) - (var(--cw) * var(--overlap) )) * var(--unit));
  height: calc(((2 * var(--cw)) - (var(--cw) * var(--overlap) )) * var(--unit));
  font-size: calc(( var(--cw) * var(--overlap) * 2 * var(--unit)) / 7.5);
  margin: 10vh auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  width: calc(var(--cw) * var(--unit));
  height: calc(var(--cw) * var(--unit));
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 3px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 50%;  
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: absolute;  
  perspective: 100px;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in;
  display: inline-block;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circleactive {
  transform: scale(1.2) rotateY(180deg);
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 900;
}

.circleactive .text {
  opacity: 1;
}

.circletitle {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 3.8vmin;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  text-shadow: 5px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.isactive .circletitle {
  opacity: 0;
}

.circle1 {
  --bg: rgb(33, 218, 223);
  --opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.circle2 {
  --bg: rgb(95, 216, 21);
  --opacity: 0.78;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.circle3 {
  --bg: rgb(253, 45, 45);
  --opacity: 0.8;
  bottom: 0;
  left: calc(50% - ((var(--cw) / 2) * var(--unit)));
}

.circle::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: var(--bg);
  opacity: var(--opacity);
}

.circle.circleactive::before {
  --opacity: 1;
}

.circle .side {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.circle span {
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(184, 184, 184, 0.70);
  rbackdrop-filter: blur(4px);
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
}

.circleactive span {
  opacity: 0;
}


.circle1 span {
  margin-right: 50%;
}

.circle2 span {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

#section1 {
  height: 100vh;
}

#section1 h1 {
  color: black;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* ideas for fitting text in a circle taken from https://css-tricks.com/using-css-to-set-text-inside-a-circle/#:~:text=1%20First%20up%2C%20the%20HTML.%20We%E2%80%99re%20going%20to,outcome%2C%20and%20human%20engagement%20as%20an%20explicit%20 */

.quote-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
}

.text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

.text p {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.text::before {
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  shape-outside: polygon(
    0 0,
    98% 0,
    50% 6%,
    23.4% 17.3%,
    6% 32.6%,
    0 50%,
    6% 65.6%,
    23.4% 82.7%,
    50% 94%,
    98% 100%,
    0 100%
  );
  shape-margin: 7%;
}

.text p::before {
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  shape-outside: polygon(
    2% 0%,
    100% 0%,
    100% 100%,
    2% 100%,
    50% 94%,
    76.6% 82.7%,
    94% 65.6%,
    100% 50%,
    94% 32.6%,
    76.6% 17.3%,
    50% 6%
  );
  shape-margin: 7%;
}

 .quote-wrapper {
    margin-top:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }

  .text p {
    font-size: calc((var(--cw) * var(--unit) / 16));
    }
    
  .text {
    opacity: 0; /* Firefox needs this Chrome/Edge do not */
  }

section > p {
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="section1" class="section">
  <div id="ven_diagram">
      
    <span class="circletitle">Mental Health</span>
    <div class="circle circle1 side" onmouseleave="if (this.classList.contains('circleactive')) removeActiveClasses();"><span>Mind</span>
      <div class="quote-wrapper" style="transform: rrotateY(180deg);">
        <div class="text">
          <p>has to do with how a person thinks, feels and acts as he or she copes with life. A person with good emotional health can feel, express and respond to a wide range of emotions in healthy ways and form healthy relationships with others</p>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="circle circle2 side" onmouseleave="if (this.classList.contains('circleactive')) removeActiveClasses();"><span>Social</span>
      <div class="quote-wrapper" style="transform: rrotateY(180deg);">
        <div class="text">
          <p>has to do with your relationships with others. People with good social health can connect with and contribute to family, friends, and the wider community</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="circle circle3 side" onmouseleave="if (this.classList.contains('circleactive')) removeActiveClasses();"><span>Spiritual</span>
      <div class="quote-wrapper" style="transform: rrotateY(180deg);">
        <div class="text">
          <p>has to do with how you find meaning and purpose in your life. People with good spiritual health have a sense of something bigger than themselves and their own day-to-day lives</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <p>Mental wellness according to the World Health Organization, is defined as “a state of well-being in which the individual realizes his or her own abilities, can cope with the normal stresses of life, can work productively and fruitfully, and is able
      to make a contribution to his or her community.”</p>
</section>
```